# Как программно прижать ImageView вправо к границе родителя LinearLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

У меня создаётся Activity примерно таким способом:

```
final ImageView ivPic = new ImageView(this);
    ivPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    ivPic.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    ivPic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    ivPic.setMinimumWidth(20);
    ivPic.setMinimumHeight(20);
    ivPic.setMaxHeight(25);
    ivPic.setMaxWidth(25);

    TextView tvDate = new TextView(this);
    tvDate.setText("fasfsafsafasfa sdfdsfsdfsdfds fsd fsdfs df sdf sdfsd fsd fsdfsd");

    LinearLayout llImage = new LinearLayout(this);
    llImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    llImage.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    llImage.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 18);
    llImage.addView(tvDate);
    llImage.addView(ivPic);
```

Проблема в том, что выводимый текст прижат влево, а картинка также прижата влево к тексту, а хочется, чтобы картинка была прижата к правому краю LinerLayout. 
Как прижать ImageView к правому краю?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько способов.

Например задайте для TextView ширину в 0 и вес в 1

Или поместите меж текстом и картинкой `Space` с такими же параметками - ширину в 0 и вес в 1

Или используйте FrameLayout и gravity